# React HOC with 'recompose' and 'redux-cycles'. How to make it work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, recompose

So, I've been playing around with [recompose](http://ttps://github.com/acdlite/recompose) and then, I've discovered this [redux-cycles](https://github.com/cyclejs-community/redux-cycles), which I think it's great for what I'm aiming: functional JS and reactiveness.

The problem is that I can't make the event listener work when I create the component using HoC(Recompose). *Ps: event listener works when I create regular React Components*

In the recompose API, there is some [Observable Utilities](https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#observable-utilities), and I think this is where my code is failing. Guess I need that to make redux-cycles work together with recompose, but I couldn't make it work.

Working example with regular React Component and 'redux-cycles': [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/bomugapuxi/2/edit?js,output)

Since it works with regular React Components and regular redux store (no 'redux-cycles'), I'll just post the HoC code:

```
/* eslint no-console: ["error", { allow: ["warn", "error"] }] */

import React from 'react';
import {
  compose,
  onlyUpdateForPropTypes,
  pure,
  setObservableConfig,
  setPropTypes,
  withReducer,
  withPropsOnChange,
} from 'recompose';
import xstreamConfig from 'recompose/xstreamObservableConfig';

import counterReducer from '../reducer';

setObservableConfig(xstreamConfig);

const enhance = compose(
  pure,
  onlyUpdateForPropTypes,
  setPropTypes({
    counter: React.PropTypes.number,
    increment: React.PropTypes.func,
    decrement: React.PropTypes.func,
  }),
  withPropsOnChange(['counter'], ({ counter }) => ({ counter })),
  withReducer('counter', 'dispatch', counterReducer, 0),
);

const Counter = enhance(({ counter, dispatch }) => (
  <div>
    <h1>Counter module</h1>
    <p>{counter}</p>
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT_ASYNC' })}> + </button>
    <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'DECREMENT_ASYNC' })}> - </button>
  </div>
));

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`recompose/withReducer` doesn't connect to your Redux store. Instead, it creates a local store in your HOC which works like redux. So if you want to consume from a Redux store, you should use [`react-redux/connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options).

Comment: It does connect with the store. Without Redux-cycles it works fine.

Comment: Oh, I get what you are saying. My bad. Will try that.

Comment: @KadoBOT does everything go well?

Comment: Yeah it did work with 'connect', but I'm still not convinced that there isn't a turnaround using one of the observable utilities from 'recompose'.

Comment: You can use recompose's Observable utilities after `connect()`, ex: `compose(connect(), mapPropsStream())`

Comment: That seems better. Will try that.